# Android application not displaying the 3d model

Tags: android, vuforia

I have made an app in unity 3d. It **detects the image and display the model.** Now i import it for the android platform. I followed the instruction from this link

https://developer.vuforia.com/forum/faq/unity-how-can-i-extend-unitys-android-activity#

**The apk file exported from unity works well.**

**But when i export the same from eclipse it doesnot show the model. I also cant find the model inside the files exported from the unity to eclipse. Please help me.**

Answer (score 0):

As far as i know Unity 3D engine doesn't let you export model into eclipse unless you have the pro version which costs 1500$.
 if you are using the trial version you have exported it into a different model not the one eclipse uses.